# Why do I need to "reinstall" Puppeteer by running `node install.js` after `npm install`? (Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded.)

Tags: chromium, puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

Otherwise, when I try to run tests using Puppeteer, I get `Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install"`

It would seem that `npm i` with Puppeteer in my deps would be enough, but after install completes, I need to `cd` into `/node_modules/puppeteer` then run `node install.js` to get the correct revision downloaded.

When I do initial `npm i` I see

```
> puppeteer@1.13.0 install /Users/.../node_modules/puppeteer
> node install.js

Downloading Chromium r549031 - 76 Mb [====================] 100% 0.0s
Chromium downloaded to /Users/.../node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-549031
```

But this doesn't work and I get the revision error.

After I `node install.js` in Puppeteer's dir, I see

```
Downloading Chromium r637110 - 85.9 Mb [====================] 100% 0.0s
Chromium downloaded to /Users/.../node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-637110
```

then I am good to go.

Any ideas why? This is on macOS & Node 10.15 and I assume it's going to be more difficult to do this in CI.

I have searched around and found others with this problem, but no solid ways around this.

package.json

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
        "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "eslint": "^5.14.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
        "husky": "1.1.2",
        "jest": "^24.1.0",
        "jest-puppeteer": "^4.1.0",
        "lint-staged": "7.3.0",
        "prettier-eslint-cli": "4.7.1",
        "puppeteer": "^1.13.0",
        "webpack": "^4.29.5",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
        "webpack-shell-plugin": "^0.5.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, another module's `package.json` had added `puppeteer_chromium_revision` to my `.npmrc` and was effectively hardcoding a revision for Puppeteer.

Answer (score 8):

I only managed to fix the above issue by manually installing Chromium using the below command on the command line

```
node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
```

Comment: Using Yarn instead of `npm install` worked on an Ubuntu server environment.

Comment: using yarn instedad npm worked for me

Comment: This worked for me when using bun as a package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps to potentially resolve this issue,

- Try using `puppeteer` as **dependency** rather than **devDependency**.
- remove any lock file like `yarn.lock` and `package-lock.json`
- clean npm cache forcefully `npm cache clean --force`
- clean yarn cache (if yarn is installed) `yarn cache clean`
- Now that all cached data is gone, you can feel free to run `npm install` again.
- If this produces the same error you faced previously, try using `yarn`.
- If that does not fix the error, then try installing exact puppeteer version with `yarn add puppeteer@1.13.0` instead of `^`.

You do not have to go inside `node_modules` folder, and you do not have to follow above steps all the time, it's just the cache might be broken somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have actually tried all of these steps (I did again just now) and have the same results. I agree this is not how it's supposed to work, but it's the issue I am hitting.

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3588#issuecomment-444169087

Answer (score 0):

**Following steps worked for me:**

- Removed lock file(like yarn.lock and package-lock.json)
- Cleaned npm cache forcefully (npm cache clean --force / yarn cache clean)
- Ran npm install

Answer (score 0):

I was installing puppeteer on an Ubuntu server and using `npm install` didn't work. I installed Yarn, and used that instead. It worked.